# VS/C# Unit tests for SFTP Client // Mocking an SFTP Server

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, sftp, mstest

I'm trying to figure out how to create a unit test for code that generates and uploads text files to an SFTP server.

I've tried running a local SFTP server for the unit tests to access, but it's messy and sometimes causes more problems.

I'm looking for a way to run an in-memory SFTP server from within the testing framework so it can be used by any developer, without having to start installing additional software.

I spent some time trying out a few things on nuget, but the only ones I can find seem to require a license. I don't really want to start buying SFTP Server licenses for something that is simply to test code.

I was wondering whether there was an open-source SFTP server that's written in c# that I could add to my tests?

How do SFTP users handle testing their code that interacts with SFTP servers?